# How to display detailed Hibernate log?

Tags: sql, hibernate, spring-boot, logging

I have a Spring Boot application with multiple endpoints and database operations and sometimes is difficult to find the location of a specific sql call.

It's possible to change Hibernate logs to show detailed logs based on the sql ?
Now the output is like:

2020-01-15 16:40:23.059 DEBUG 24348 --- [nio-8083-exec-2] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select id, name from ......

But i want to show java origin class instead of "org.hibernate.SQL".

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable the logging of the SQL statements

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG, myLogger
```

and also the actual parameters passed to the queries

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=TRACE, eclLogger
```

The log originator will always be the Hibernate logger (org.hibernate.SQL), I guess you want to log your DAO method? You will need to add that in your code (obviously in case of exceptions you can log the entire stack and see the invocation chain)

Comment: i was wondering if it's some configuration to show me the DAO method automatic without logging manually myself.